# How similar is 3.5e White Plume Mountain to 5e White Plume Mountain?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, published-adventures

I want to run White Plume Mountain for my players, but one of them has played the 5e version of this module.  I want to run the 3.5e version, adapted for 5e.

I know that these modules have some differences based on [this](https://www.enworld.org/threads/white-plume-mountain-tales-of-the-yawning-portal-play-report-spoilerific.543073/) play account (spoilers).  The most obvious difference seems to be that, in the 5e version, you can

> reach Keraptis's Indoctrination Chamber.  (but sadly it's not described in more detail)

**How spoiled will my player be?**

Comment: @SteveED: [Answer in answers, not in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)

Comment: @cpcodes please don't use the comments to answer. See the above comment.

Comment: I'm not happy with how this is turning out.  I posted a question and the only answer I got was "lol I havent done any research but I know that wont work".  I did the research myself and the other guy called me "nitpicky", like he thinks he knows better than me what level of detail I wanted.  Now the other guy has edited some token research into his answer, and mysteriously people seem to think that makes his answer better, so they keep downvoting me?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems I can't delete my question, either.

Answer (score 3):

Your player will be super spoiled as they've already played the module.

According to the [product page for White Plume Mountain Revised (3.5) on Dungeon Masters Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170094/White-Plume-Mountain-Revised-35):

> The 3.5e version of "White Plume Mountain" is based closely on the original, with the design adjusted in some areas for balance and better polish. The three named weapons have also been statted up with the Weapons of Legacy (2005) system.

And, according to [Tales from the Yawning Portal](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/tales-yawning-portal), the original *White Plume Mountain* has been

> updated to the fifth edition rules.

Having compared both 3.5e and 5e versions side-by-side, all of the differences between the two are merely cosmetic or mechanical in nature. There are only two minor, *legitimate* differences between 3.5e and 5e:

> The turnstile in 5e is a mimic in 3.5e (area 6), and the 3.5e map is shifted to force players to go through area 23 before going to area 26.

I like both of these 'changes', but they are cosmetic at best. The first is little more than a new wandering monster, and the second just determines in which order players enter rooms.

Comment: I actually was hoping for an answer from someone who's familiar with the 3.5e and 5e versions. Still, it's good to hear about your experience!

Comment: Someone familiar with the original *is* familiar with the 3.5 and 5e versions; that’s the point.

Comment: @KRyan: I've read the 3.5e .pdf. Sure, there are some cosmetic differences. Some of them are even pretty cool, but the bottom line is that none of them _fundamentally change the module nor the encounters therein_. The whole point of the original question was whether or not the player will be 'spoiled' because they've played the 5e version.

Comment: Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Instead, you should edit your answer to stand as if it were always the best version of itself; anyone interested in older versions can view the revision history.